# How to determine if a registry key exists in Wix

Tags: wix, registry

I want to determine if a Registry key exists in Wix. I cannot make any assumptions about value names in that key, but at least one exists. Default value is not set. Is it possible to check if the key exists (and optionally, if it has any values) without using custom actions?

Comment: Answer is you can't, see this for more information:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327203/in-wix-how-do-i-test-for-the-existence-of-a-registry-key-not-value-for-oracle][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327203/in-wix-how-do-i-test-for-the-existence-of-a-registry-key-not-value-for-oracle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327203/in-wix-how-do-i-test-for-the-existence-of-a-registry-key-not-value-for-oracle

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the RegistrySearch

Sample of use:

```
    <Property Id="MYRegSearch" Value="AVaLue" Secure="yes">
        <RegistrySearch Id="RegSearch" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\!(wix.Manufacturer)\!(wix.ShortProduct)" Name="Values" Type="raw"/>
    </Property>
```

Comment: I know about RegistrySearch, but I don't know how to use it to check if a key exists

Comment: I would put a flag value to the property like -1, then you can check in a condition that the property is different than -1

Comment: As default key value does not have a value set, Property value doesn't get changed. It seems I will need custom action to test it.

Comment: If the key exists the value will change, otherwise it will stay the same.

Comment: @CheGueVerra not true at all... what if value is empty? If you are looking for default value for example... and it is not set, then your property will not be changed...