# Installer to copy files to existing directory

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I need to create an installer file, which copies a set of XML files into the directory of an existing application, which is already assumed to be installed on the computer. The installer wraps a plugin (consisting of a set of XML files) for a popular CASE tool.

I would prefer if this can be done using a combination of WiX with an MSI package as the output so that it can be deployed easily to corporate environments.

The installer must do the following:

1. Ask the user for the target directory in which the existing application is installed (defaulting to `C:\Program Files\AppName`).
2. Copy two XML files into `C:\Program Files\AppName\SubDir`, and create SubDir if it doesn't already exist
3. Finish the install.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Anders

Comment: yes and http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/main.htm

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And you should do your best to auto-detect the install location of the AppName, by searching the registry and/or file system. This can be done with WiX/MSI.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these posts it will help you on your way.

[Search the registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439442/how-to-determine-if-a-registry-key-exists-in-wix) for installed apps

[Custom directory search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354619/wix-how-to-do-a-directorysearch-in-a-custom-installation-location)

[Basic installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200743/wix-script-with-only-welcome-and-completed-screens/259685#259685)

Good luck