# How to search a (Default) registry entry with value (value not set) from WIX?

Tags: wix

How can we search a (Default) registry entry with value (value not set) from WIX?I tried by using RegistrySearch without Name attribute still its not working.Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`(value not set)` is not a real value. It's just what you see in regedit when the `(Default)` value for the  key is actually not set.

If you do a `RegistrySearch` search for a value that is not set, or a registry key that does not exists, then in both cases the windows installer property will not be set. You cannot make the distinction between both.

So how do you verify that a registry key is present or not? The simplest way is to search for another value that is always set when the key is present, instead of searching for `(Default)`. Typically there is one. If not, you'll have to write your own custom action as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327203/in-wix-how-do-i-test-for-the-existence-of-a-registry-key-not-value-for-oracle-o/1340107#1340107).

Comment: Thanks wcoenen.Is it possible to check if folder like SOFTWARE\Microsoft is present in the registry?

Comment: registry folder == registry key, so my answer stays the same.