# WiX RegistrySearch in all subdirectories

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I need to check whether an any version of some product is already installed.

```
<RegistrySearch Id="MyId"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Company\{ANY FOLDER}"
                  Name="MY_KEY_NAME"
                  Type="file"  />
```

Is it possible to use RegistrySearch for searching in all subdirectories?

Comment: Do you mean recursion of registry subkeys?

Comment: Thanks guys!
I used the custom action as was described here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1340107][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1340107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppSearch / RegLocator doesn't support recursion.  You'll either need a custom action or change the way you store data in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge and from the [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html) I see nothing that points to RegistrySearch recursing through directories. To do that you'd need to use a custom action. Another possibility and one we used on an installer was to search on the UpGradeCode e.g.

```
 <Upgrade Id ="other product's guid">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="0.0.0.0" Property="OTHERPRODUCTDETECTED" IncludeMinimum="yes" />
 </Upgrade>
```

You would need a block such as this for every product you are attempting to search for, which requires knowing all the guids.